Which Wolfi package supplies libudev development headers
I'm building a project that uses libudev development headers on Wolfi OS (cgr.dev/chainguard/rust:latest-dev). I know on Debian-based distros the required package is libudev-dev, but there is no such package on Wolfi. Searching for udev doesn't seem provide any suitable package:
$ apk search udev
eudev-3.2.14-r2
eudev-dev-3.2.14-r2
eudev-doc-3.2.14-r2
eudev-hwids-3.2.14-r2
eudev-libs-3.2.14-r2
eudev-netifnames-3.2.14-r2
libinput-udev-1.26.2-r0
py3-udev-0.24.3-r1
systemd-256.4-r0
systemd-dev-256.4-r0
zfs-udev-2.2.5-r0

Is there a simple way to get pkg-config --libs --cflags libudev to work under Wolfi?

Yes, the systemd-dev package actually includes the libudev.pc file for pkg-config. Just run sudo apk add systemd-dev.
